# Listings package and forcing inclusion of empty lines at end of line ranges?

Tags: listings

By default, the listings package suppresses empty lines at the end of the file, and this behavior can be switched off with the option `showlines`.

However, listings also suppresses empty lines at the end of each range in a `linerange`. Consider the following Java source file:

```java
public class Example implements StringHandler {

    /** 
     * Prints the given string.
     *   
     * @param s  the given string
     */  
    @Override
    public void handle(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

And this is the LaTeX source file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{slides}
\usepackage{color,listings,courier}

\lstset{language=Java,%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
  numbers=left,%
  numberstyle=\tiny,%
  commentstyle=\color{blue}\itshape}

\begin{document}

% Suppress complete javadoc and @Override (to avoid cluttering the slide)
\begin{slide}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={1-2,9-13}]{Example.java}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

The expected output is:

```java
public class Example implements StringHandler {

    public void handle(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

But instead, I get

```java
public class Example implements StringHandler {
    public void handle(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Line 2 (which is empty) is not included in the output, being at the end of a line range.
(I am using listings v1.5; but v1.3 behaves similarly.)

It turns out that empty lines at the *beginning* of a line range (consisting of more than one line) are included. But that is of no help in this situation.

How can I force the inclusion of these embedded empty lines? This is useful to make the listing more readable.

The options `showlines` and `emptylines` do not affect this behavior.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @user2768: No, I never a solution.