# How to preserve trailing blank lines in lstinputlisting with linerange option?

Tags: listings, white-space

Here is my code in `foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={1-2,7}]{foo.tex}

\end{document}
```

This code in `foo.tex` reads itself and displays itself as code listing. But it tries to show only line 1, line 2 (blank line) and line 7 (the last line).

The output PDF contains only two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\end{document}
```

Line 2 (blank line) does not appear in the PDF output. It looks like trailing blank line was ignored. I tried adding the `showlines=true` option but that did not work too. How can I preserve the blank line in line 2 in the final PDF output?

Comment: This bug seems to have been around for quite some time: [Listings package and forcing inclusion of empty lines at end of line ranges?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233445/listings-package-and-forcing-inclusion-of-empty-lines-at-end-of-line-ranges)